# I am trying to create cascading drop down from json data using Angular JS

Tags: html, angularjs

I am trying to create cascading drop down from json data using Angular JS but not able to populate data on second dropdown based on Item you select on first drown.
Can any one sugeest me where i am doing mistake

HTML:

```
<select ng-model="asset 1" id="assetNameGroup"  ng-change="populateSection(this)"      ng-options=" x.name for x in Nameitems">
      <option  value="">Select Name</option>
   </select>
   <select ng-model="asset2" id="assetNameGroup2" ng-     change="populateSection2()" ng-options=" x.name for x in asset1.sections">
  <option  value="">Select Name</option>
 </select>
```

JS

```
    // Code goes here 
       var app = angular.module("myApp" ,[]);
     app.controller('sensorsCtrl', function($scope, $state, $http) 
         alert("");

    $http.get(sample.json).success(function (resp) {
        $scope.innerIsIsLoading = false;
        $scope.assetData = resp;


          $scope.Nameitems = [];

           var testobj = $scope.assetData[0].name;
         angular.forEach($scope.assetData, function(val,key) {
         $scope.Nameitems.push ({"name": 
          val.name,"uri":val.uri,"sections":  val.sections});
              console.log("console.log(JSON.stringify-----=                                                                                                               "+JSON.stringify
                ($scope.Nameitems));
           });
          console.log("$scope.assetData"+JSON.stringify($scope.assetData));

        $timeout(function() {

          //$scope.SequenceLinkTableData=$scope.assetData;
        }, 100);
        });


       $scope.populateSection=function(value)
         {
           var checkvalue = value;
              console.log(value);

     var Namesite =                              document.getElementById('assetNameGroup').value.split("/")[2];
        alert(Namesite);
            }

                });


              Json:

                    [{
             "uri": "/assets/0ff042ea-45e6-32e1-915b-81efa58e924e",
        "name": "Asset 1",
           "sections": [{
               "uri": "/assets/67dc7db3-2374-314d-8b19-6be09d4203c9",
              "sectionId": null,
    "name": "Section 1",
    "ultrasonicSensors": null,
    "temperatureSensors": null,
    "ultrasonicSensorPositions": [{
        "ultrasonicSensorPositionId": 1392,
        "sensorPositionName": "MeasurementPosition 1",
        "diameter": 12,
        "rotation": 270,
        "sequenceNumber": null,
        "sectionId": "/assets/67dc7db3-2374-314d-8b19-6be09d4203c9"
    }, {
        "ultrasonicSensorPositionId": 1428,
        "sensorPositionName": "MeasurementPosition 2",
        "diameter": 12,
        "rotation": 270,
        "sequenceNumber": null,
        "sectionId": "/assets/67dc7db3-2374-314d-8b19-6be09d4203c9"
    }]
}, {
    "uri": "/assets/8d2c61f7-eb3e-3170-9e0b-dc26b2b574f5",
    "sectionId": null,
    "name": "Section 1",
    "ultrasonicSensors": null,
    "temperatureSensors": null,
    "ultrasonicSensorPositions": [{
        "ultrasonicSensorPositionId": 1390,
        "sensorPositionName": "ultrasonic sensor position 1",
        "diameter": 22.5,
        "rotation": 90,
        "sequenceNumber": null,
        "sectionId": "/assets/8d2c61f7-eb3e-3170-9e0b-dc26b2b574f5"
    }, {
        "ultrasonicSensorPositionId": 1427,
        "sensorPositionName": "MeasurementPosition 2",
        "diameter": 12,
        "rotation": 270,
        "sequenceNumber": null,
        "sectionId": "/assets/8d2c61f7-eb3e-3170-9e0b-dc26b2b574f5"
    }, {
        "ultrasonicSensorPositionId": 1445,
        "sensorPositionName": "MeasurementPosition 3",
        "diameter": 12,
        "rotation": 270,
        "sequenceNumber": null,
        "sectionId": "/assets/8d2c61f7-eb3e-3170-9e0b-dc26b2b574f5"
    }]
}]

         }]
```

[plunker link](https://plnkr.co/edit/q4Qn5U9PFsJ04gGpzwFV?p=preview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second `ng-options`, change from `asset1.sections` to just `asset1`:

```
ng-options="x.name for x in asset1"
```

**Demo:** https://plnkr.co/edit/r3zrGrAT4PweKw1aLpe6?p=preview